# JavaFX / TreeTableView: Relationship between Selection and Focus

Tags: javafx, focus, selection, treetable

I need some clarification on the relationship between `Focus` and `Selection` in `javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView`.

In my code I have defined:

```
ttvMainTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
```

Assumption 1: I was assuming, that the focused item is always the last item with left-click. Also I was assuming that the a left-click always moves the selection. So that in `SelectionMode.SINGLE` the focused item  and the selected item are always identical.

This seemed to be correct in 90% of all situations. Anyhow after some random left-clickes my code produced such a picture:

[image]

Kindly confirm:

- The item with the blue background is the selected item
- The item with the blue border ist the focused item

Here the focused item can be changed with left-click, the selected item seems to be not influenced by left-click.

My apologies for not providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). At the moment I don't know how to shorten my code and reproduce this behavior.

Therefore a general question:

- What is wrong with assumption 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, i don't think there is a difference on the behavior of the two, it is rather a **relationship** as you said, when you select a `Node`, this one request the focus.
The focus can be controlled with the "`focusTraversable`" :

> **focusTraversable** : Specifies whether this Node should be a part of focus traversal cycle. When this property is true focus can be moved to this Node and from this Node using regular focus traversal keys.

For your case I think maybe it's because you have chosen a `TreeTableView` that is both child and parent `Child 2` !

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason for the odd behaviour of my application:
A selection listener caused update of the datamodel. Basically the list with child-elements was deleted an populated again with the same data. This caused confusion in the selection model.